# MDX passing variable as string to Item()

Tags: variables, mdx, mondrian

I have my MDX query as follow:

```
with set SelectedEntity as '{Union({[Category].[Tertiary Category].Members}, {[Category].[Secondary Category].Members}).Item("Emails")}'
select Crossjoin({[Measures].[Reach]}, {[Age Group].[15-17], [Age Group].[18-24], [Age Group].[25-30], [Age Group].[31-35], [Age Group].[36-40], [Age Group].[40+]}) ON ROWS,
{[SelectedEntity]} ON COLUMNS
from [AppUsage]
where {[Country].[India]}*{[Date].[2011].[April]}*{[Panel].[Syndicate]}
```

Here in place of `Item("Emails")` I want pass a variable something like this `Item(${category})`. Hence my query should become something like this:

```
with set SelectedEntity as '{Union({[Category].[Tertiary Category].Members}, {[Category].[Secondary Category].Members}).Item(${category})}'
    select Crossjoin({[Measures].[Reach]}, {[Age Group].[15-17], [Age Group].[18-24], [Age Group].[25-30], [Age Group].[31-35], [Age Group].[36-40], [Age Group].[40+]}) ON ROWS,
    {[SelectedEntity]} ON COLUMNS
    from [AppUsage]
    where {[Country].[India]}*{[Date].[2011].[April]}*{[Panel].[Syndicate]}
```

But try to pass this `category` variable to this query it gives me error as Failed to parse the query.

I am not getting where am going wrong? Is this the correct way to pass a variable in Item() as it needs the string.

Note: `${category}` variable value I am getting after selecting an entity into the Auto-complete field which I want to pass to the above query

***EDIT:***

When I pass the value 'Emails' for category variable in the query, i.e. in above `Item(${category})`, in logs the same query becomes `Item(Emails)`. But instead of this it should be something like this: `Item("Emails")`.

I need to know how do I pass this variable as a string in my mondrian MDX query.

Comment: Which reporting tool are you using? The syntax for an MDX parameter is @category

Comment: I am using Mondrian for MDX in Pentaho

Comment: I did as per your suggestion but couldn't succeed. I am getting the same error. Also I found this: "Parent exception: Mondrian Error:Failed to parse query" in logs. which specifies it is still not able to do parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

The variable needed to be passed as `Item("${category}")`. Hence my query will become:

```
with set SelectedEntity as '{Union({[Category].[Tertiary Category].Members}, {[Category].[Secondary Category].Members}).Item("${category}")}'
    select Crossjoin({[Measures].[Reach]}, {[Age Group].[15-17], [Age Group].[18-24], [Age Group].[25-30], [Age Group].[31-35], [Age Group].[36-40], [Age Group].[40+]}) ON ROWS,
    {[SelectedEntity]} ON COLUMNS
    from [AppUsage]
    where {[Country].[India]}*{[Date].[2011].[April]}*{[Panel].[Syndicate]}
```

where `${category}` is my variable.